# Is there a modalViewControllerDidEnd method for modal view?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I present some navigation controller modally

```
[self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
```

How can I detect if modal view did end? Is there some delegate method?

Comment: What about `viewDidLoad` method of nevController or it subViewController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no method or notification sent.

I implement this with my own delegate protocol all the time.

I've posted a code example for a delegate pattern as answer to this question: [delegate and passing data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861316/delegate-and-passing-data/5861610#5861610).

There is a method called `somethingHappenedTellMyDelegate` this should be trigger close to your `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:`

Comment: How do I implement my own. Can you give an example plz.

Comment: @ArtWorkAD I've added a link to an example.